# Primefaces AutoComplete lose entered value when mouse click outside the component or minimize the page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

All primefaces autocomplete object components (POJO,Custom Content,Multiple..) lose entered value when mouse click outside the autoComplete component or when minimize the page, so please is there any way to hold the entered value ?

**SOLUTION :** 
ForceSelection attribute force autoComplete to accept only input from selection list this is why the autoComplete clear the entered value, so to solve it :

```
forceSelection = "false"
```

Comment: Version info? Code example?

Comment: just go to [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml)  and verify all the autocomplete ojbects components they clear entered value when mouse click on the blank or minimizing the page @Kukeltje

Comment: does not happen for me

Comment: i just found the solution, forceSelection attribute force autoComplete to accpet input only from selection list this is why when it was enabled the autoComplete cleared the entered value, SOLUTION : forceSelection = "false"